# Designing/looking for a circuit board for a vaporizer

Tags: arduino, voltage, pcb, watts

I recently decided to look for/create a board for a vaporizer and have no idea where to start. I will probably end up programming the program in C or C++. To better explain this, I will explain the function and components I need. I will use two 3.7v 18650 batteries. The batteries power the board. The board ideally needs to output 10 amps using 5 volts. The board need the capability to check the resistance of a coil in which the batteries heat up. There are 3 buttons. 1st button to heat the coil up and the other 2 to switch between wattage. Changing the wattage changes the voltage and amp output. The program has to do the following.

1. I need to measure the resistance. (Ohms) To do that I first need to know the voltage the battery is generating. The starting voltage and wattage will be preset. (The watts need to be preset anyways since it's needs to be displayed.) Then, using the ohm's law algorithm I can calculate that by using,
   Amps = Watts / Voltage
   Ohms = Voltage / Amps
2. The watts are displayed and are controlled by the user. By changing the watts it then changes the voltage and amps.
   Amps = sqrt(Watts / Ohms)
   Voltage = Amps * Ohms

Question: 
Is my logic flawed in anyway?
Does anybody know of a board that can do this?
If I have to build my own board, what are the components I need?

Comment: Drug paraphernalia?

Comment: You do realize that a pair of 3Ah batteries is going to be able to deliver 50W for only about 15-20 minutes, right?

Comment: Indeed, as Dave mentions this is a HUGE power output for such a small power source. Fix that part of your spec first. Next I suggest you find some kind of IC that can do constant current controlling for such large currents - 10A is quite high on the scale of power controllers for normal use (not huge industrial stuff)

you could use Current Shunt Monitor ICs like the texas instruments INA138 to help display "Power" usage, while the microcontroller you choose can read the voltage input using its ADC.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  haha! what if it's for homebrew rum? An alcohol still might use a similar setup?

Comment: Oh, I'm just looking to get this to work. I don't care about how long it's going to last atm. But thanks for the the heads ups.

Comment: KyranF thanks for the info, I will look into that.

Comment: @KyranF Maybe it should use a 4-20 mA sensor?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  for what? current measurements? or the input voltage ADC readings?

Comment: also @user39702  the issue with such high currents is the power electronics behind it is perhaps out of your capability.. I've been designing and successfully made some pretty crazy stuff, including a 120A pulsed LED strobe array, but they were for short on-times, to allow heat dissipation. The control circuitry if you use an IC like this http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/37411fe.pdf  will be difficult to get right the first time, if you have no experience. That IC can control up to 20A and 10V output by the way, but costs $10.

Comment: @KyranF I think I will limit it to be used 7 seconds at a time. And a wait time of 2 seconds. Something like that. Btw, Has anyone ever use a LM317? Looks like something I might need.

Comment: an LM317 is a very basic and old technology adjustable linear voltage regulator. I sincerely hope you do not use it for this application, other than simple low power for a controller or something. Because you are using battery power, perhaps look at the Texas Instruments line of "Simple Switcher" high efficiency converters with 1A output, and lots of nice protection in them. They will take anything from 8-40V and give you nice 5V 1A output. follow reference designs and you will be safe...

Comment: @KyranF Holy ..., thanks alot! The LMZ31710 is exactly what I'm looking for! My entire build will evolve around this. Maybe.

Comment: @user39702 please be extremely careful with that IC, read every single word of that datasheet. For example, making sure cycle-by-cycle current limit is used rather tha hiccup fold-back mode. 

You will need pretty hardcore thermal relief, and I suggest putting a fan on it or something. 

please note the IC's package is going to be extremely hard for an unskilled solderer to place onto a PCB. 

The device does indeed fullfil all your requirements, but again, holy crap please take it slow and use the reference designs. dont do 10A loads (effectively shorts) first. staged testing over long times!

Comment: Also that IC is quite expensive, http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LMZ31710RVQT/296-37035-1-ND/4485014  

at around $22/IC plus shipping. There are much cheaper alternatives but the circuitry will be complicated (using current shunt monitors, and MOSFET power switching your own way. will have much less cool protection circuitry though..)

Comment: @KyranF Thank you for the advice, I just bought the evaluation module from TI. Hopefully a little easier to test on. I forgot to mention that I want to display everything as in Voltage, Ohms, maybe amps, and Watts. Is there a small OLED where I can fit everything on there? Btw, I should of mentioned this earlier I'm trying to make something like this http://www.evolvapor.com/datasheet/dna30.pdf I don't exactly want to copy them but come close to that.

Comment: @user39702  haha, thats a cute little power monitor. Well you can easily make your own, like i said a current shunt monitor IC from Texas Instruments INA138 will give you a voltage output directly related to current through the sense resistor, and a simple microcontroller can read the input voltage, and you do some maths on a controller and display on whatever little LED/LCD screen you can buy for cheap. there are lots on the market, just find one that is simple SPI or software serial

Comment: if you would like, in 6-8 hours or so I can package up all these comments into an 'answer' for you, so that i may be voted as the answer?

Comment: @KyranF funny enough, in the US, a still is more illegal than weed tools are. But vapes are more commonly known as e-cigarettes, not for illegal drugs.

Comment: @DaveTweed vapes are e-cigs. On for a few seconds at any given time.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this might require software or a microcontroller? Sounds like a basic analogue control problem to me

Comment: @KyranF That would be awesome.

Comment: @user39702 there ya go mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sorry if the flow doesn't quite make sense, this is a summary (mostly copy paste) of Q&A that occurred in the comments of the original question*

As Dave Tweed mentions (he's a good bloke) this is a HUGE power output for such a small power source. Fix that part of your spec first. Next I suggest you find some kind of IC that can do constant current controlling for such large currents - 10A is quite high on the scale of power controllers for normal use (not huge industrial stuff) you could use Current Shunt Monitor ICs like the Texas instruments INA138 to help display "Power" usage, while the microcontroller you choose can read the voltage input using its ADC

The issue with such high currents is the power electronics behind it is perhaps out of your capability.. I've been designing and successfully made some pretty crazy stuff, including a 120A pulsed LED strobe array, but they were for short on-times to allow heat dissipation.

The control circuitry if you use an IC like this: cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/37411fe.pdf 
will be difficult to get right the first time, if you have no experience. That IC can control up to 20A and 10V output by the way, but it costs $10 alone.

Because you are using battery power, perhaps look at the Texas Instruments line of "Simple Switcher" high efficiency converters with 1A output, and lots of nice protection in them. They will take anything from 8-40V and give you nice 5V 1A output. follow reference designs and you will be safe...

Be extremely careful with the LMZ31710 if you plan to use it; read every single word of that datasheet. For example, making sure cycle-by-cycle current limit is used rather tha hiccup fold-back mode. You will need pretty hardcore thermal relief, and I suggest putting a fan on it or something. please note the IC's package is going to be extremely hard for an unskilled solderer to place onto a PCB. The device does indeed fullfil all your requirements, but again, holy crap please take it slow and use the reference designs. dont do 10A loads (effectively shorts) first. staged testing over long times! There are much cheaper alternatives to that IC but the circuitry will be complicated (using current shunt monitors, and MOSFET power switching your own way. will have much less cool protection circuitry though..)

For the power monitoring side of things, you can easily make your own - like i said earlier a current shunt monitor IC from Texas Instruments INA138 will give you a voltage output directly related to current through the sense resistor, and a simple microcontroller can read the input voltage, and you do some maths on a controller and display on whatever little LED/LCD screen you can buy for cheap. there are lots on the market, just find one that is simple SPI or software serial.